# User callback doing nothing slows down Cplex

Tags: cplex, cplex-python-api, callback

I am trying to do something with user callbacks in Cplex using Python API. For instance, I will need a callback that only counts the number of explored nodes.

While testing something I noticed that for one problem, without a user callback, Cplex solves it very quickly (3s). But if I register a user callback that does **nothing** it does not stop even after 5 minutes. Is this normal? I would expect that such callback should not interfere with how Cplex is working. (Similarly my hope was that I could count the number of visited nodes seamlessly).

Comment: Depending on the version of cplex, adding a callback will disable dynamic search, which most likely will slow down the solver. Especially if you add nothing that should counter balance this, e.g. add a cut or heuristic callback

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you please explain what dynamic search is?

Comment: actually, when I create a model, I disable all the various features to be as close as possible to vanilla B&B: `cplexmodel.parameters.mip.strategy.search = 1`, so it should then be something else, right?

Comment: "Thanks for the comment. Could you please explain what dynamic search is?" It's the name of the custom algorithm used by Cplex by default which is not documented

Comment: Looking at the node logs from runs with and without the callback (and with dynamic search disabled as in the comment), are there differences in the per-node progress on primal and dual bounds, or is the run with the callback visiting the same nodes but just more slowly?